# Can the OS X keychain juggle two accounts for the same site?

Tags: password, login, keychain

I have a different passwords for:

1. `www.example.com/foo/login` and
2. `www.example.com/bar/login`

It seems as if the keychain only saves the passwords in relation to the *sitename* as it does not make distinctions by the *subdomain*.

When I visit `www.example.com/foo/login` the keychain will save the password correctly, but when I visit `www.example.com/bar/login` afterwards it uses the password of the first page and doesn't let me create a new password for the subdomain.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Just as a side note: [1Password](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1password/id443987910?mt=12) can store a different passwords for different domains, I guess it should also work for subdomains. Just create two logins and change the URL entry. It's currently on sale in the Mac App Store.

Comment: @gentmatt well it seems to be a good app but I would like to manage to configure keychain correctly and use this. In keychain I create two logins for the two subdomains and place them in the "where" fields but it doesn't make any difference. It is as if it only checks the domain only. Is it actually is a subfolder in the domain? Is that important?

Comment: I've edited your question in an attempt to attract more attention to it and make it easier to read. Let's hope someone around here will be able to help you. :)

Comment: That's the problem I have with keychain access.  The real problem is that it's so easy to replace that other password without knowing which password it has in memory.  I'm working with Wordpress with WPEngine and all these passwords are just swapping each other out.  I'm constantly resetting passwords... with that said, I'm starting to check out Bitwarden, but I'm trying to decide how I feel about having two password managers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you'll want a more full featured password manager like the one [gentmatt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13414/gentmatt) recommended in the comments.

You could do some kludgey web proxy to give the subdomain a separate top level domain, but that's way more hassle than most would consider appropriate for solving the problem you pose.

Comment: I see. I liked keychain and i wanted to stick with it.

Comment: I just thought I’d highlight a scenario where 1Password (and its ilk) is not a solution. I'm currently using Git through the command line and have been trying to see if I can connect the same project to two different remote repos located in different GitHub accounts.The GitHub password is stored in Keychain. Terminal.app accesses the password directly from there — there's no way (AFAIK) that 1Password can interact with Terminal. And Keychain cannot store multiple PWs for GitHub.com, even if I qualify them with extra URL components (e.g. github.com/userfoo and github.com/userbar).

Comment: @tioschi there is a one password command line tool.  I don’t fully understand your use case, so I won’t say it solves it, but I would bet a lot of people use 1Password command line and get in our happy with it. No matter if it works or not, excellent point about commandline integration and that being an awesome feature

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, for the same domain I needed two passwords with the same username, one for a Web-based access via browser, one for access with an App.
Workaround: Added a string of text (e.g. -Web or -App) to the username. That I delete just when presented with the log-in screen when iCloud/Keychain had filled the fields already. And don't ever update the password then ...
Annoying, best is to report it to apple.com/feedback